# How to check an element exist in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<library>
    <book>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>abc</name>
         <read>
          <data>yes</data>
          <num>20</num>
        </read>
    </book>
    <book>
      <id>20</id>
      <name>xyz</name>
         <read>
          <data>yes</data>
        </read>
    </book>
    <book>
      <id>30</id>
      <name>ddd</name>
    </book>
</library>
```

From this I am reading the `<book>` node with element `<id>` value = 20 using below code

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("e_test.xml")
XElement book = root.Elements("book")
                    .Where(x => (int) x.Element("id") == 20)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
if (book == null)
{
    // No book with that ID
}



if(book.Element("read").Element("num") != null) //check the node exist
{
    int num = (int) book.Element("read").Element("num");
}
```

Here the if condition is not working correctly. It is passing the condition and get inside and giving null exception. Is this the right way to check the same?

I am using .NET FRAMEWORK 4.0

Comment: You've said which version of .NET you're using, but not which version of C# you're using. They're not the same thing.

Comment: I just tried your code with that xml and did not get a null reference exception.  There seems to be something missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for `null` for each of `Elements` calls:

```
if(book != null && book.Element("read") != null && book.Element("read").Element("num") != null) //check the node exist
```

in C# 6 you can use `?.` operator to make it feel nicer:

```
if(book?.Element("read")?.Element("num") != null) //check the node exist
```

Comment: Another approach would be to use `Elements("read").Elements("num").FirstOrDefault()`.